# How to reset jquery datatable bStateSave for next record search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using jquery datatable for displaying list of records.

The work flow of this problem is like the following:

1. A user enter "test" in search box. it will return list of customer name.
2. After click on next button of datatable it display next 10 records.
3. When I click on customer name it display customer details.
4. after click on browser back button it comes back to list of customer. but it returns to 1 page instead of 2 page.
   For this problem I have used "bStateSave=true"(presumably saves state for reloads) which keeps user on 2 second page. this is fine.

Here's our problem:

But when user go for another search in search box and enter text it display page 2. However, the user wants to see page 1 first, since he has posted a new query.

I tried "iCookieDuration=60" to clear bStateSave. but it clear after 60 seconds.

Is it any alternative way to achieve both things?

Answer (score 3):

Your use case works for me using jQuery DataTables version 1.7.6. Today I just started to use the same option as you to save table state in a cookie. I do not use any other initialisation parameters as you can see below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#charts').dataTable( {
            "bStateSave": true
        });
    });
```

Comment: Since version 1.10.X jQuery DataTables uses HTML 5 LocalStorage instead of cookies to save table state.